# No module named 'feedparser'

Tags: python

I have installed python 3.3.3 and downloaded the feedparser-5.1.3 from "https://code.google.com/p/feedparser/downloads/list" and installed that parser. i also checked the parser at this location: "C:\pyhton33\Lib\email" and the file is there with name "feedparser". But i do not know why it is not importing and giving me constant error "No module named 'feedparser' ". Here is the code:

```
import feedparser
import re
# Returns title and dictionary of word counts for an RSS feed
def getwordcounts(url):
  # Parse the feed
  d=feedparser.parse(url)
  wc={}
  # Loop over all the entries
  for e in d.entries:
    if 'summary' in e: summary=e.summary
    else: summary=e.description
    # Extract a list of words
    words=getwords(e.title+' '+summary)
    for word in words:
      wc.setdefault(word,0)
      wc[word]+=1
  return d.feed.title,wc
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\generatefeedvector.py", line 1, in <module>
    import feedparser
ImportError: No module named 'feedparser'
```

Any help please.

Comment: Are you sure the file is under `C:\Python33\Lib\email`? That `email` on the end suggest its in the `email` package. Try `import email.feedparser` and see if that works.

Comment: Actually, reading a bit more, that's a different module (for reading email feeds, not RSS feeds). Your feedparser module is probably installed somewhere else (or it never got installed properly in the first place).

Comment: yes i carried search and found that in this folder. can i show u screen shots? if i am wrong then tell me where it could it be?

Comment: the only location i am getting is C:\python33\Lib\email  i dont know whether it is correct or not...:(

Comment: If its in C:\python33\Lib\email, then its in right location. I installed the module and imported it in interpreter and I didn't got any error. Since you are getting the error, it simply means you didn't installed it properly, can you tell what installation steps you followed?

Comment: i simply started the setup which was in feedparser-5.1.3.zip and black screen appeared and finished after some seconds of waits.

Comment: Can you install this way:
Open CMD, cd to the directory after unzipping feedparser-5.1.3.zip
type : `python setup.py install`
If everything goes right, you will success message on prompt, after that try importing the file in Python interpreter, let us know what happens.

Comment: yes thanks for proper reply but it is giving import Error : "No module named 'setuptools' "

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution and it worked on my computer (Python 3).

Referencing https://www.geeks3d.com/hacklab/20190118/how-to-use-feedparser-and-atoma-to-read-rss-feeds-in-python-3/.

Download feedparser from author's page https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser.

To install feedparser, unzip the repo to:

```
C:\Users\The_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\
```

"cmd" window to install it (full line) as:

```
C:\Users\The_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\feedparser-develop>python setup.py install
```

python setup.py install